# JDBC connection fail after change JVM heap size

Tags: jdbc

Due to the lack of heap capacity, I follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992911/mathematica-j-link-memory-constraints to increase the heap size, but afterward, I cannot connect to the DB even, throw me very simple message: connection failed, here is the connection string:

`conn = OpenSQLConnection[
  JDBC["org.postgresql.Driver", 
   "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/zhanglingtao"], 
    "Username" -> "zhanglingtao", "Password" -> "08113"]`

Before I change the heap size, heap error happens when I try to retrieve a lot of rows; but after change, I cannot even connect to the DB. Even worse, I have to shutdown and reboot the whole system to get the connection work again.

Please help, many thanks.